# css-javascript How show css popup with javascript

Tags: html, css

this my first question. i have some code but i dont know how to tell you my mind. let see the code ->

When i show dialog, in the url bar, there is '#openModal1'. how to hide with javascript or something.

```css
.modalDialog {
  position: fixed;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  z-index: 99999;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.modalDialog:target {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.modalDialog>div {
  width: 600px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 10% auto;
  padding: 5px 20px 13px 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #fff;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
}
```

```html
<a href="#openModal1">open</a>

<div id="openModal1" class="modalDialog">
  <div>
    <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
    <h2>Modal Box 2</h2>
    <p>This is a sample modal box that can be created using the powers of CSS3.</p>
    <p>You could do a lot of things here like have a pop-up ad that shows when your website loads, or create a login/register form for users.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you want show and hide with javascript `#openModal1`?

Comment: Welcome to **StackOverflow**. I really recommand you to read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This will help you a lot on this website.

Comment: I think he has a URL such as `http://www.website.com/page#openModal1` when he opens the modal window, but he doesn't want this ` #openModal1` in his URL.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you can modify the javascript you use to open the modal but maybe you could use `data-attributes` instead of an anchor.

```
<a href="javascript:;" data-modal="openModal1">Black</a>
```

Then modify the javascript according to the `data-attribute`.

```
$('a').on('click', function() {
    var selector = $(this).attr('data-modal');
    $('#'+selector)... // open modal function 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
<a href="#" onclick='openModal1'>open</a>

<div id="openModal1" class="modalDialog">
  <div>
    <a href="#" onclick='close' title="Close" class="close">X</a>
    <h2>Modal Box 2</h2>
    <p>This is a sample modal box that can be created using the powers of CSS3.</p>
    <p>You could do a lot of things here like have a pop-up ad that shows when your website loads, or create a login/register form for users.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```